# Qooxdoo client side protection mechanisms

Tags: javascript, web-applications, client-side, qooxdoo

What are the protection mechanism for client side javascript application in qooxdoo?

Basicly I know how to handle the login process using some server application, but I am wondering how can I protect my application source code from being stolen and reused by someone else?

I know the javascript obfuscation mechanisms, etc., but I am looking for some more secure solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After running the qooxdoo generator build, your code will already be pretty 'user unfriendly' I highly doubt that it would make much sense for anyone to try and reverse engineer from that ... especially since most JS applications rely heavily on their server backend anyway.

Have you tried debugging a 'built' qooxdoo app? Then you know what I mean ...